# Is it possible to know the username executing a cap task to use it from inside Capfile?

Tags: capistrano

Do you know if it's possible to access the username running the 'cap deploy' task to use it from a cap task in the Capfile?

For example, we need to mark a deploy in newrelic after doing a deploy, so I added a task "mark_deploy" in the capfile that does the work. The problem is that it will be nice to register the user running the 'cap deploy', but for that I need to know the username at the time the "mark" task is invoked.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It's solved, I discovered that there is a global variable in Capistrano that you can use just for this:

```
#{local_user}
```

Thanks for the help!